# Using Pinch in zoom in webview with a local html gets distorted

Tags: android, html, webview, zooming, pinch

I have a webview in which a local html file is opened. This local html file is using Google Javascript API to open Google Maps. 
I had set webview.getsettings().setbuiltinzoomcontrols to true. 
Pinch Zoom is happening but the webview scale is getting distorted. Please tell if anybody knows the reason why is it happening.
Thanks and Regards
Astha Devra

Answer (score 2):

webview.getsettings().setbuiltinzoomcontrols enables scaling of the webview as a whole (just like stretching an image), and does not communicate with the JavaScript code.

You will notice same thing happening if you open Google Maps on Android Web Browser instead of running the native Google Map app.

You can capture the pinch gesture with onTouchListener and set the zoom value of Map in JavaScript by webview.loadUrl("javascript: YOUR_ZOOM_IN_FUNCTION").

Answer (score 1):

The WebView on most android 2.x devices does not generate more than one touch event in javascript and instead zooms the browser content - thus the "distortion".

In order to support those devices you can enhance your web container to generate those missing events - which we have done before with [this "Polyfill" you may find on github](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill).

Also make sure your html header prohibits user scaling by setting a viewport meta-tag like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`